# Java Web Security

Tags: java

Вот web.xml файл. Используется Tomcat server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error-pages/error404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login-form.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login-error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>retail</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

Для аутентификации использую JDBCRealm (из базы данных).

Блокирую доступ для всех страниц, но тут возникают проблемы.
Вначале идет переход на `index.jsp` но ресурсы не появляются (Например фоновая картинка). После успешной аутентификации кидает вот сюда 
`http://localhost:8080/images/escheresque_ste.png`
в проекте это `web/images`.
При этом логинится успешно.
Как решить эту проблему и почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ресурсы блокируются, потому что стоит ограничение **<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>**. Они ведь загружаются посредством **GET** запроса. Надо праивльно написать **<url-pattern>** тэг

*Обновление*

[[@nba-world](/users/19541/nba-world)](/users/19541/nba-world) 
надо написать еще один блок

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>PublicAccess</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
<security-constraint>
```

Маппинг будет осуществляться по наиболее подходящему *<url-pattern>*. В данном случае доступ к папке *images* пройдет через *PublicAccess*.

Блока *<auth-constraint>* нет, это значит, что нету ограничений по ролям

Comment: меня интересует как правильно